# Update state for component by event handle in other component in different file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component in my project one is Tag and the other is LandingTicker so i want when i click Tag componet update state for LandTicker componet, and landticker componet in different file.

how i can do that?

thank you.

Tag component code::

tag/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.scss';

class Tag extends React.Component {

    handleClick(e) {

        let tags = document.querySelectorAll('.show-clickable');

        Array.from(tags).map(el => el.classList.remove('selected-tag'))

        e.target.classList.add('selected-tag');

      /*
          Here i should update the state for LandingTicker component. 
          and remember any component in different file.
          How i can do that??? 
      */
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="show-clickable"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
                click here
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Tag;
```

LandingTicker component code::

LandingTicker/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import TickerRow from './TickerRow';
import './index.scss';

class LandingTicker extends React.Component {   
   state = {
      coin: 'USD'
   }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="landing-ticker__body">
                    {selectCoin(this.state.coin)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const selectCoin = (coin) => {
    const coins = {
        USD: ['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'EOSUSD', 'LTCUSD'],
        EUR: ['BTCEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'EOSEUR'],
        GBP: ['BTCGBP', 'EOSGBP'],
        JPY: ['BTCJPY', 'ETHJPY'],
    };

    return (
        coins[coin].map(el =>
            <TickerRow symbol={el} key={el.toString()} />
        )
    );
}

export default LandingTicker;
```

Edit:

my component Hierarchy::

> StatusTable
>
> ```
>   TagsTable
>
>           Tag
>
>   TickerSearch
>
>   LandingTickers
>
>           TickersRow
> ```

StatusTable component code::

```
import React from 'react';
import TagsTable from './TagsTable';
import TickerSearch from './TickerSearch';
import LandingTicker from './LandingTicker';
import './StatusTable.scss';

class StatusTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="status-table">
                <TagsTable />

                <TickerSearch />

                <LandingTicker />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default StatusTable;
```

Comment: state in React belongs only to a single component, so there's no direct way to update another component's state. But you can easily pass the state down to the child component as a prop, so that when it updates the child is also updated. (Components are re-rendered when either their state *or* their props change.)

Answer (score 0):

React handle all its component data in the form of state and props(immutable). So it is easy to pass data from parent to child or one component to another using [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) :

Your Tag.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import LandingTicker from "./LandTicker";
class Tag extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      trigger: true
    };
  }
  handleClick(e) {
   // do all logic here and set state here
    this.setState({ trigger: this.state.trigger });


  }

  render() {
    //And then pass this state here as a props
    return (
      <div className="show-clickable" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        click here
        <LandingTicker trigger={this.state.trigger} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tag;
```

Inside LandTicker.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import TickerRow from './TickerRow';
import './index.scss';

class LandingTicker extends React.Component {   
   state = {
      coin: 'USD'
   }

    render() {
       //Catch your props from parent here 
       //i.e this.props(it contains all data you sent from parent)
        return (
                <div className="landing-ticker__body">
                    {selectCoin(this.state.coin)}
                </div>
        );
    }
}

const selectCoin = (coin) => {
    const coins = {
        USD: ['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'EOSUSD', 'LTCUSD'],
        EUR: ['BTCEUR', 'ETHEUR', 'EOSEUR'],
        GBP: ['BTCGBP', 'EOSGBP'],
        JPY: ['BTCJPY', 'ETHJPY'],
    };

    return (
        coins[coin].map(el =>
            <TickerRow symbol={el} key={el.toString()} />
        )
    );
}

export default LandingTicker;
```

Comment: but the problem i don't call LandingTicker inside Tag.

Comment: Then manage state in statusTable and pass props there i.e pass data from tags to statusTable and then pass state to your LandingTicker component.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best answer for your question if you don't use state management system such as Redux or Mobx.
https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17
(you need to check third option)